# Overlap between tests

Tags: probability, correlation, normal-distribution

If two ability tests are normally distributed and correlate .6, what percentage of the population have scores that are at least one standard deviation below the mean on at least one of these tests?

Comment: Are the two *bivariate* normal? Or is it just that the margins are normal? (in which case we need to know what the dependence structure is)

Comment: The answer could be as small as 16%.  This is achieved (approximately) when the first test scores $x$ are normally distributed with mean $m$ and the second score is (a) the same as the first test score when it is more than one standard deviation away from its mean $m$ and (b) equal to $2m-x$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a bivariate normal is intended, this can be done via a a variety of numerical integration approaches (e.g. see Genz, 2004 [1]); these are available in a variety of packages (including in `mnormt` and `pbivnorm` in R).

```
library(mnormt)
1 - biv.nt.prob(df=Inf, lower=c(-1,-1), upper=c(Inf,Inf), 
                  mean=c(0,0), S=matrix(c(1,.6,.6,1),nr=2))
[1] 0.2447846
```

There are also some old sets of tables available.

We if a precise answer is not required, we can also use simulation to get a few figures of accuracy:

```
 x=rnorm(10000000)
 y=.6*x+.8*rnorm(10000000)
 mean((x< -1)|(y< -1))
[1] 0.2447808
```

We can also calculate a standard error or a binomial proportion confidence interval to construct an interval around that simulated estimate (which gives a sense of the precision).

```
 p= mean((x< -1)|(y< -1))
 sqrt(p*(1-p)/10000000)
 [1] 0.0001359644
```

So we should have good 3 figure accuracy but not quite 4 figure accuracy with that simulation. [Comparing with the 'exact' answer calculated earlier, we were lucky and actually got about 5 figures right, but we normally wouldn't know.]

[1] Genz, A. (2004),
"Numerical computation of rectangular bivariate and trivariate normal and t probabilities"
*Statistics and Computing*, (Aug.), **14**:3, pp. 251-260
[Working paper [here](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/papers/bvnt.pdf)]